# Adding additional fields on user registration page (first name, last name)

Tags: 7, users, forms

In Drupal 7, what methods are there to add additional textfields to the user registration page at /user/register? I mainly want to also get their first + last name during registration. There doesnt seem to be a way via the interface to add these extra fields as required for sign up.

What is the quickest way of adding these extra text fields on sign up?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to goto:

**Administration » Configuration » People » Account settings » Manage fields**

[image]